# Request.IsAuthenticated is always false in IE(8)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

### Logon Action in AccountController

```
                // Logon Logic.

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserInfo, model.RememberMe);

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
```

---

**Web.Config**

---

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="TestRadarManager" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="false" />
</authentication>
```

---

**HomeIndex.cshtml**

---

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <span>Welcome,</span><b>@Context.User.Identity.Name</b>
                }
```

---

It works fine in FF browser,but Request.IsAuthenticated is always false in IE anyway,
Thanks you in advance for helps.

Comment: Is IE blocking the cookie locally? Your privacy settings _may_ be too restrictive.

Comment: It's ok, to visit other site on the same server is alright